# How to create shortcut and send it to Windows' Startup folder in one click?

Tags: windows, boot, shell, shortcuts

Is there a shell extension or some program which lets you do it in one click? How do you get it to automatically create a shortcut (like the premade Send to “Desktop (create shortcut)” version)?

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this with any folder.

Depending on your OS (you did not specify), find the Start Menu and create a shortcut of the Startup folder.

Drop it into the Sendto Folder.  Now you can right click any program and use Send To. . .

Comment: You can get to the Sendto folder by typing "shell:sendto" into the start menu search or the location bar of an explorer window.

Comment: When I tried this, it copied the file I had right-clicked into Startup instead of creating a shortcut. How do you get it to automatically create a shortcut (like the premade Send to “Desktop (create shortcut)” version)?

Answer (score 2):

If you want this to work on files as well (not only shortcuts), you can use a script that makes a shortcut instead of just copying the file.

I did this myself with this vbscript:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set lnk = oShell.CreateShortcut(oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\") & FSO.GetFile(WScript.Arguments(0)).Name & ".lnk")

lnk.TargetPath = WScript.Arguments(0)
lnk.Save
```

Save it as "Startup (create shortcut).vbs" in the sendto folder.

Comment: This is great, thanks! Is there a way to adjust the script to omit the `.exe` extension from shortcuts to programs?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Run <kbd>Win + R</kbd>, type `shell:sendto`
2. Copy the folder you want the file to send to. In this case the Startup folder locates in `shell:startup`.

See more: [List of `shell:` commands](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/shell-commands-to-access-the-special-folders/)